# Button should remain vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I want to center align the button vertically, It should remain aligned vertically even if `height` and `line-height` of `li` is changed, or `font-size` of the button is changed.

```css
 ul {
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
}

 ul li {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

 ul li.header-logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#button {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    background-color: #ff9191;
    border: 2px solid #00b5cc;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-row">
    <ul>
        <li class="header-logo">AAA</li>
        <li><div id="button">BUTTON</div></li>
        <li>LINK</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a display:inline to your button - and it should be fine

```css
 ul {
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
}

 ul li {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

 ul li.header-logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#button {
    display:inline;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    background-color: #ff9191;
    border: 2px solid #00b5cc;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-row">
    <ul>
        <li class="header-logo">AAA</li>
        <li><div id="button">BUTTON</div></li>
        <li>LINK</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```